# How do dual monitors work while gaming?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, external-display, gaming

I'm thinking of getting a 2nd monitor and utilizing the extended desktop function. What I'd like to know:

- How would this work if I wanted to play a game? Would I be able to have the game appear only on one monitor? Also, does this incur any performance penalties?
- I've been reading that when playing games, the second monitor freezes, and it's essentially useless. So would I not be able to play a game on one monitor and browse the web on the second?
- Would I also have to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>/minimize the game I am playing on the main monitor in order to get the mouse to the second monitor?

Answer (score 3):

> I'm thinking of getting a 2nd monitor and utilizing the extended
>   desktop function. Could you please let me know how this would work if
>   I wanted to play a game?

- Some games, not all support multiple display outputs to create a sort
  of "panoramic" viewing experience. You'd one to consult the game's
  FAQ to check for yourself.

> Would I be able to have the game appear only on one monitor?

- Most games only appear on one screen unless configured otherwise.

> Would I be able to have the game appear only on one monitor? Also does
>   this incur any performance penalties? I've been reading that when
>   playing games the second monitor freezes and it's essentially useless.

- Using two screens for a game will definitely hinder computer performance if it isn't high enough spec to support it, the key components being your graphics card and CPU.

> So would I not be able to play a game on one monitor and browse the
>   web on the second?

- When I run a game full screen on my first monitor I still able to
  watch a movie or something on my second monitor. Unless your game is
  running in windowed mode you will need to tab out to use your mouse
  on the other screen.

> If my game is in windowed mode, will the mouse stay within the edges
>   of the screen? Like if I was playing SC2/Civ 5/etc, would the mouse be
>   able to move the screen when I drag it to the sides or will it jump to
>   the second monitor?

- It would stay "locked" in to your game unless you alt+tab out of it.
  It will not be possible to move your mouse out of the game window whilst you are playing.

Comment: If my game is in windowed mode, will the mouse stay within the edges of the screen? Like if I was playing SC2/Civ 5/etc, would the mouse be able to move the screen when I drag it to the sides or will it jump to the second monitor?

Comment: Whether a game properly captures the mouse pointer varies widely. Sometimes, phantom hover effects can be observed on secondary displays.

Comment: @DanielB I'm well aware, happens to me very occasionally but it shouldn't do ;)

Comment: Your last point isn't 100% certain.  I still play Civ 3 on my two-monitor system, and I can mouse out onto the other monitor (if I click on anything, it does still minimize the game).

Comment: @Brian Some games for some reason do sometimes allow the mouse to "jump" out of the game window. Usually during a transitional phase of gameplay and you click and it minimizes the game. As far as I know this is a an issue to do with the game, rather than any configuration on the machine.

Comment: That sounds right.  Civ 3 is the only example I can think of that acts this way - everything else I play in full-screen mode locks the mouse to that monitor.

Comment: @Brian I experience it sometimes with CS:GO, I think maybe it's a DirectX thing ;)